# Mixture of Experts WIth Choice of Expert

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a keras neural network classifier.

This model takes as input a tensor of shape (batch_size, 20, 10) and performs a binary classification.

I would like to increase the classification accuracy and I thought that the Mixture of Experts (MoE) mechanism could help me achieve a better accuracy.

So I'm trying to create multiple models (experts) and then use the MoE mechanism to select the best K experts to process each (20, 10) input of the batch.

My idea was to implement a keras layer that behaves like a router.

Something like this:

```
from keras.layers import Layer

class MixtureOfExperts(Layer):
    def __init__(self, experts: list[Layer], **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.experts = experts
        ...
    ...
```

This layer should behave like a router. When the layer is called on a batch of inputs, each input should be processed by the K best experts.

How can I complete this class' code to implement the desired behavior? Assume that each expert has the same output shape